# Downloading zip files in R

Tags: r, file, zip

I am trying to download several zip files from https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/drugsfda-data-files.  On this page, there's a download files link Drugs@FDA Download File (ZIP - 3.54MB).  Is there a way to do this in R without clicking on the download link? When I click on the link, it download the files onto my PC and I am trying to do it in R all at once.  Thank you.

Comment: I only see one zip file on that page. What exactly are you referring to? Do you want to just download that one zip file? You can download files in R with the `download.file()` function, ie `download.file("https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download", "fda.zip")`

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I did that and when I try to unzip it, it doesn't work unfortunately.  Here's the code I used.  Thank you!!!

download.file("https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download", "fda.zip", mode='wb')

destfile <- "C:\\Users\\Name\\Downloads\\"

unzip("fda.zip", files=NULL, list=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE,

       junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = "destfile", unzip = "internal", setTimes = FALSE)

Comment: The zip file has two files, *ActionTypes_Lookup.txt* and *ApplicationDoc.txt*. Windows app 7zip.exe is giving me an error when trying to open *ApplicationDoc.txt*.

Comment: I had mode="wb".  Thanks for your help!